# PayPal Adaptive Chained Payments: How to hide Secondary Receivers from Sender?

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

[Documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) says:

> Chained payments are useful in cases when the primary receiver acts as
>   an agent for other receivers. The sender deals only with the primary
>   receiver and does not know about the secondary receivers, including
>   how a payment is split among receivers.

I'm doing this request:

```
{
    "returnUrl": "http://localhost", 
    "currencyCode": "USD", 
    "receiverList": { "receiver": [
        {
            "amount": "5.00", 
            "email": "vladimir.sapronov-facilitator@gmail.com",
            "priamry": true
        }, 
        {
            "amount": "10.00",
            "email": "vladimir.sapronov-shop@gmail.com"
        }]}, 
    "actionType": "PAY", 
    "cancelUrl": "http://localhost", 
    "requestEnvelope": {"detailLevel": "ReturnAll", "errorLanguage": "en_US"}
}
```

I was expecting to see the invoice for $15 to vladimir.sapronov-facilitator@gmail.com which is Primary Receiver. But I see:

facilitator account's Test Store $5.00 USD

VLADIMIR SAPRONOV $10.00 USD

Total: $15.00 US

It doesn't look like "sender deals only with primary receiver". How to make it the way it's described in the documentation - want to see only transaction for $15 to Primary Receiver?

Comment: Please check the spelling, it is priamry, you shoud set it to primary, Most probably this solves your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comment from @antoniom is absolutely right. Also the amount to primary receiver should be changed to be more then amount to secondary receiver.

Here is right working example:

```
{
    "returnUrl": "http://localhost", 
    "currencyCode": "USD", 
    "receiverList": { "receiver": [
        {
            "amount": 15.00, 
            "email": "vladimir.sapronov-facilitator@gmail.com",
            "primary": true
        }, 
        {
            "amount": 10.00,
            "email": "vladimir.sapronov-shop@gmail.com"
        }]}, 
    "actionType": "PAY", 
    "cancelUrl": "http://localhost", 
    "requestEnvelope": {"detailLevel": "ReturnAll", "errorLanguage": "en_US"}
}
```